# how to read textfiles in raw folder by clicking listview

Tags: android

I have a ListView in my main activity that I want to click and have it open the text files in the raw folder in the second activity. I've tried running it but I just displays a blank screen in the second activity. Here's my main activity code.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ArrayAdapter<String> aAdpt = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
        new String[]  {"book 1", "book 2", "book 3"});   //the strings that appear on the actual list view

        final int rawIds[]= {R.raw.books1, R.raw.books2, R.raw.books3};
        String data = readTextFile(this, R.raw.books1);
        ListView lv=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.mylist);
        lv.setAdapter(aAdpt);

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                Intent i = new Intent (getApplication(),Readlist.class);
                i.putExtra("rawIds", rawIds[position]);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }

    public static String readTextFile(Context ctx, int resId) {
        InputStream is=ctx.getResources().openRawResource(resId);
        InputStreamReader isr= new InputStreamReader(is);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        String line;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        try {
            while ((line = br.readLine()) !=null) {
                sb.append(line);
                sb.append('\n');
            }
        } catch (IOException e){
            return null;
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

And my second activity

```
public class Readlist extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.readtext);

        String rawIds = getIntent().getStringExtra("rawIds");
        TextView text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtread);
        text.setText(rawIds);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`rawIds` is an `int[]`. Hence, `i.putExtra("rawIds", rawIds[position])` is storing an `int` extra. I am not sure exactly what `getIntent().getStringExtra("rawIds")` will return in this case (either the `int` formatted as a `String` or `null`), but it will not be the text from the raw resource.

Passing the `int` of the raw resource is a reasonable move. However, you then need to move the read-in-the-raw-resource logic into the second activity.